# Using Regex for a Purchase Order

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm not sure this is even possible

I was given a requirement to match Purchase Order numbers within a filename.
His requirement is below:

*I would say a minimum of 4 characters, with no max limit. However there MUST be a string of 3 consecutive LETTERS (minimum) somewhere in this section.*

123ABC - match
A123ABC - match
ABC123 - match
123XY67 - NO match
ABC1VJ6K - match

The best I can come up with is [0-9A-Z]{4,}; however, that matches basically ANY 4 characters

Answer (score 2):

you can use this pattern:

```
[A-Z0-9]*?[A-Z]{3}[A-Z0-9]+|[A-Z0-9]+?[A-Z]{3}[A-Z0-9]*
```

An other way with a lookahead:

```
(?=[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z]{3})[A-Z0-9]{4,}
```

And why not, if your regex engine allows conditional:

```
([A-Z0-9]+?)?[A-Z]{3}(?(1)|[A-Z0-9])[A-Z0-9]*
```

Comment: Thanks Casimir...  I'm going with the (?=[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z]{3})[A-Z0-9]{4,}